# how to call a php variable within a javascript colorbox

Tags: php, javascript, colorbox

i have a problem with javascript. i´d like to use colorbox to display some responsemessages. is there anyone who knows how to refer to a php script variable within a javascript?

to bring an example

```
<?php if(isset($msg)):?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.colorbox({iframe:true, href:"<?php print variable $message from this site", scrolling:false, innerWidth:"408px", innerHeight:"292px", opacity:0.75, overlayClose:false, escKey:false, });
});
$("#colorboxCloseBtn").click(function() {
$.colorbox.close();
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i´m not sure if i do understand the usage of iframe, inline, html. if i use iframe this will open a complete idependent site without any relation to the mainpage, isn´t it? inline i use, when i would like to relate on content which is on the mainpage, like i like to, right? and html... don´t know.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, this is barking up the wrong tree the way you're doing this, you need to put message into a session then have href get the full url of the new file then have that file echo nothing but $message:

```
//EG:your.php
<?PHP       
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
   if(isset($msg)) {
     ?>        
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $.colorbox({iframe:true, href:"message_get.php", scrolling:false, innerWidth:"408px", innerHeight:"292px", opacity:0.75, overlayClose:false, escKey:false });
            $("#colorboxCloseBtn").click(function() {
                $.colorbox.close();
            });
        });
     </script>
   <?php 
   } 
 ?>
```

then a whole new document

```
//EG: message_get.php
<?PHP       
   session_start();
   echo $_SESSION['message'];
?>
```

to be honest i'd get rid of the iframe you probably don't need it because this is a very ineligant way of doing this. You look to me like you've learnt ASP.NET first

Comment: hello and thanks for posting. this is working like i dreamed of :) the only thing i do not understand is that errormessage that i will get when i will call the page: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: the call to `session_start();` on `your.php` has to be *right* at the top

Comment: problem is that the box need its own installation. means that before i can call the function it needs to be defined with a link to css and the js file. when i set it to top another errmessage will be shown: Warning: Unknown: Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect which existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be advised that the session extension does not consider global variables as a source of data, unless register_globals is enabled. You can disable this functionality and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42 or session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively in Unknown on line 0

Comment: ok. The Error message is because sessions=cookies and cookies cannot be sent after you've started piping html out.. cookies *must* get nominated in the document header (you don't see/smell/touch that header 99 times out of a 100 it's *not* the `<head>` tag)..

Comment: so to fix it you need to make sure you call `session_start()` somewhere up the "include tree" (you can use `DIE("dead !".__FILE__.__LINE__);` to degbug view the source in your browser until the "dead!" text appears *above* the very first bit of HTML pipe  (EG: `echo` and `print` and `response.write` all output to the html pipe) read more here [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php[/link]

Comment: wouldn´t it be possible to set a session at the top on which i can relate after the php for registration and the introducing head?

Comment: thats it. i had to start the session on top and relate on it after the whole php and header phrases. thanks alot. have a nice weekend. best wishes

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(isset($msg)):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $.colorbox({iframe:true, href:"<?php echo $message ?>", scrolling:false, innerWidth:"408px", innerHeight:"292px", opacity:0.75, overlayClose:false, escKey:false });
           $("#colorboxCloseBtn").click(function() {
               $.colorbox.close();
           });
       });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

using `<?php echo $message ?>` will be what you are after

I have moved the `click` method inside the `ready()` function too - this ensures the DOM element is ready before attaching the click handler.

I have also removed the last comma from `escKey:false` in the `colorbox` function call

Comment: @John well ... are you sure `$message` is defined ... as your `if` statement checks for `$msg` not `$message`

Comment: yes it is. i´m using the variable from php which defines the text. if i use this the colorbox even won´t start! if i replace that with an external link like href:"example.php" that will pop up the box and show me the content of "example.php" like it should to.

Comment: @John please check that `$message` is actually set ... do `alert('message = <?php echo $message ?>');` and see what happens

Comment: the variable is set correct. i know that because the same variable will be called on another place where i created a div where i it will show up. and i even know that it is "$msg". i just posted another, sorry. <div><!--<?php if(isset($msg)):?>
        <div id="msg">
        <?php echo $msg;?>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
  </div>-->

Comment: to avoid misunderstandings:

<?php if(isset($msg)):?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.colorbox({iframe:true, href:"<?php echo $msg ;?>", scrolling:false, innerWidth:"408px", innerHeight:"292px", opacity:0.75, overlayClose:false, escKey:false, });
        });
        $("#colorboxCloseBtn").click(function() {
        $.colorbox.close();
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Automatically resize to content 
        var y = $(document.body).height();
        var x = $(document).width();
      ...
 <?php endif; ?>